# NoData specification via IEEE NaN in GeoTIFF for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, nodata

I am a programmer exporting 32-bit floating point GeoTIFF rasters from my own application that my users need to read into ArcGIS. Unfortunately I am not an Arc user myself and have *zero* expertise with it, so please target comments accordingly.

Arc is reading and locating my rasters properly, but I am having problems making it understand which grid cells are empty. Since all positive and negative floating point numbers are legal data values in my rasters, I am trying to use IEEE NaNs as my NoData values, which I understood to be an accepted practice. Furthermore, as my rasters are often dimensionally large but sparsely populated, I'm trying to get maximal compression out of the TIFF PackBits algorithm (which really likes to see sequences of identical bytes) by making an optimal choice with regard to my particular NaN value. Since any 32-bit float whose exponent bits are all 1 is considered a NaN, I'm using 0xffffffff (32 1-bits) as my NaN value since it's both a valid IEEE NaN and is also 4 identical bytes.

Arc seems to treat my 0xffffffff NaN values as low but legal values, i.e., it renders them as black similarly to the actual low legal data values in my file. How can I get Arc to treat this particular constant (which is of course *not* a value that can be expressed as a floating point number since it's an actual IEEE NaN) as my NoData value and not render it at all?

Not being an Arc user it's quite possible that I'm just not setting the right display/import options within Arc to get what I want. If someone could explain how to do this that may well solve my problem.

Comment: How does ArcGIS display your NoData value when you query the image using the identify tool?  Also, have you tried right-clicking the raster layer in the table of contents > Properties... > Symbology > Display Background Value <your value> as <No Color>?

Comment: How are you setting the NoData value in the TIFF? Are you using ESRI ArcObjects, GDAL or writing as binary using the GeoTiff specification?

Comment: Hi Aaron, the identity tool does seem to recognize my empty grid cells -- when I point and click over them the displayed panel entry says NoData, whereas clicks over filled pixels show plausible numeric values. That's a gratifyingly positive development! Unfortunately we still can't figure out any way to get Arc to render these empty cells as anything other than black. We played around with the symbology dialog but nothing we did ever altered the black rendering of the empty cells.

Comment: ... Initially the Display BG Value box was unchecked and the Value was set to 0 (but grayed out). We tried various things (like checking the box and setting the value to NaN) but nothing made any difference.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm writing my own GeoTIFF files byte-for-byte using the TIFF and GeoTIFF specs. Just looked through the latter to see if there's a special NoData GeoTIFF key, but there does not seem to be one.

Comment: What value is shown in the properties for the raster (ArcCatalog, right click on raster and go to properties)?

Comment: GDAL uses the key 42113 http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html to store the NoData value, this is not a standard key but ArcGis from v10 uses GDAL drivers to interpret raster so it should be a pseudo standard.

Comment: The ArcCatalog raster properties entry for the NoData value is empty. This seems in conflict with the identity tool which seems to know which of my grid cells are empty.

Comment: I'll try playing with that GDAL 42113 key, Michael, and see if that makes any difference, thanks.

Comment: you can use the ArcCatalog interface to set/edit the value though I'm not sure you could insert NaN in this box... with a hex editor you should be able to reverse engineer the differences in the TIFF file before and after setting the NoData value and see what keys have been added or modified.

Comment: Michael, according to [this](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/gdal_nodata.html) 42113 is a tag with an ASCII value. I guess I could try "0xffffffff" for the ASCII value but I'm not sure this will be interpreted properly given that the raster values are floats and not unsigned ints. There is no way to represent this value as a floating-point-ish string, of course, and I'm not sure how to extrapolate the simple 8-bit "255" example shown on the above-quoted page to something that will work for my 32-bit float NaN -- maybe the unsigned decimal integer equivalent "4294967295"?

Comment: Another option is to create a 1bit [internal mask](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html#internal_mask).

Comment: Hi Luke, I saw that documentation, I assume it's referring to a 2D grid with 1 bit per cell where a 1-bit means the underlying grid cell is hidden (or displayed)? I think I'd prefer to not add substantially more complexity to my files, but we'll see where this goes.  It is rather frustrating that Arc's identity tool seems to show that Arc knows those grid cells are empty, yet for whatever reason it persists in drawing them anyway as black.

Comment: I know the tag can hold values outside of 0-255, commonly I use -9999 and less commonly 65535 for unsigned data. The only way to tell for sure is to set it with catalog and review the changes in windiff or similar. It would make sense if the ASCII value is the same value type as the pixels - char pixels = char value, float pixels = float value. Bitwise there is no difference between 0xffffff as float and long so could be worth a try.